# Facebook Page not in public search results

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I have created a Facebook page a while ago, but now when i typ in the name of the Fan Page
it will show up ofcourse because i have created it.

But my friends and other people cant find it so i did check it

When you go to [this page](https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=%22The%20fanpage%22&type=pages&init=quick&tas=0.12523575998031944), it says:

> No results found for your query.
>   Check your spelling or try another term.

So i have done some google work and i saw something about the Age Restrictions i have set that also
What i also tried is changing the category.

Does anyone know whats going on here why my fanpage is not in the public results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. The page of my band "Seed Pulse" does not show on searches. But the page is accessible online using "seedpulse" as a username.

The only help I've found so far is here: http://www.facebook.com/help/issues/pages

> **Why isn't my Page showing up in search results?**
>
> Some users are currently not seeing their Pages in Search results. If you are experiencing this issue, please submit a report [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=page_not_displaying).

I reported the problem using the given link two weeks ago and did not have any feedback from the Facebook guys...

Comment: Yeah indeed after some searching i found that to ... hard to find tho ,,

For the people that have this problem you can report it to facebook here is the link :https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=page_not_displaying